# Spring / Reactive Mongo / Lookup by other collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-webflux, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following setup

```
MyCollectionOne{firstId='14', secondId='123456'}
MyCollectionTwo{_id='123456', otherFields='blah...'}
```

I am trying to do the following but am unsure of the correct syntax to use  without nesting separate queries:

```
// Find MyCollectionOne where the firstId passed in matches MyCollectionOne.firstId
// Use MyCollectionOne.secondId to lookup MyCollectionTwo by _id
// Return a Mono of MyCollectionTwo

public Mono<MyCollectionTwo> getMyCollectionTwo(String firstId) {
  // Obviously wrong syntax but trying to show the gist of what I want
  return reactiveMongoTemplate.findMyCollectionTwoWhereMyCollectionOneFirstIdIs(firstId, MyCollectionTwo.class);
}
```

Update -
I can get what I want this way but I don't like that I have to manually select every key in MyCollectionTwo. Working example is here
(https://mongoplayground.net/p/85xOusippii)

```
db.MyCollectionTwo.aggregate([
 {
  $lookup: {
    from "MyCollectionOne",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "secondId",
    as: "Temp"
  }
 },
 {
  $unwind: $Temp"
 },
 {
  $match: {
    $and: [
      {
        "Temp.firstId": firstId
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  $project: {
    _id: 1,
    otherFieldOne: 1,
    otherFieldTwo: 1
  }
}
]).find()
```

If I try to convert it to
spring equivalents it returns no results. Am I making a typo / operation error somewhere? I commented out The MatchOperation so I should see all results in the collection

```
public Mono<MyCollectionTwo> getMyCollectionTwo(String firstId) {
  LookupOperation lookup = Aggregation.lookup("MyCollectionOne", "_id", "secondId", "Temp");
  UnwindOperation unwindOperation = Aggreation.unwind("Temp");
  // MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("Temp.firstId").is(firstId);
  ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project("_id", "otherFieldOne", "otherFieldTwo");

  TypedAggregation<MyCollectionTwo> aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    MyCollectionTwo.class,
    lookupOperation,
    unwindOperation,
    // matchOperation,
    projectionOperation
  );

  this.reactiveMongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, MyCollectionTwo.class).subscribe((x) -> {
    System.out.println("Found something", +x);
  }

  // For now I don't care what I'm returning from this method as I should 
  // see something in the logs from the subscribe shown above.
  return Mono.empty();
}
```

Comment: Do you stick to the template? Because MongoDB queries can also do this with a repository.

Comment: I think I figured out a long way with MongoDb Queries (which I'll post) , but I'd prefer to use templates if possible.